# react: get custom checkbox's checked attribute

Tags: javascript, checkbox, reactjs

I want to so some customization with checkbox, it can look like this:

[image]

so I wrap my custom checkbox into a React Component:

```
require('../../less/ck-checkbox.less');
var React = require('react');

var CkCheckbox = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    name: React.PropTypes.string,
    text: React.PropTypes.string,
    defaultChecked: React.PropTypes.bool,
    onChange: React.PropTypes.func
  },
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      name: 'checkbox',
      text: '',
      defaultChecked: false,
      onChange: function () {}
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="ck-checkbox">
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name={this.props.name}
            ref="c"
            defaultChecked={this.props.defaultChecked}
            onChange={this.props.onChange.bind(this, this.refs.c.checked)}
          />
            <span className="icons">
              <span className="icon-checked-o icon-true"></span>
              <span className="icon-circle-o icon-false"></span>
            </span>
            {this.props.text.length > 0 ?
              <span className="ck-checkbox-text">{this.props.text}</span> : null
            }
          </label>
        </div>
      );
    }
});

module.exports = CkCheckbox;
```

and my container is like this:

```
var React = require('react');

var CkCheckbox = require('./CkCheckbox.js');

var Test = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CkCheckbox onChange={this._handleChange}/>
      </div>
    );
  },

  _handleChange: function(checked, e) {
    console.log(checked)
  }
});

module.exports = Test;
```

you can see that, I tried to bind `this.refs.c.checked` in the `onChange` callback, but it doesn't work.

so, how can I get the `checked state` of my custom checkbox in Test component in the _handleChange function?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In this case you don't need use `refs` because you can get checked property from `e` argument

```
// CkCheckbox component
 <input type="checkbox" 
     name={this.props.name} 
     defaultChecked={this.props.defaultChecked} 
     onChange={ this.props.onChange } />

// Test component
_handleChange: function(e) {
  var checked = e.target.checked;
  console.log(checked)
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26002/)

or if you want pass only `checked` property you can do it like this

```
// CkCheckbox component
handleChange: function (e) {
  this.props.onChange(e.target.checked);
},

<input type="checkbox" 
   name={this.props.name} 
   defaultChecked={this.props.defaultChecked} 
   onChange={ this.handleChange } />

// in Test component 
_handleChange: function(checked) {
  console.log(checked)
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26003/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example you can use to get the custom value or the value of your checked box, and also to check if the box is checked.

```
export default class SearchBoxContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      boxAll: false
    };
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ boxAll: event.target.checked }, () => {
      console.log("This returned true or false", this.state.boxAll);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-container">
        <SearchBox />
        <div className="filter-country">
          <h1>Filter</h1>
          <div className="filter-country-container">
            <div>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                id="checkBoxUS"
                name="US"
                value="US"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <label htmlFor="US">All Jobs</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It is important to know that in this example, I used the "setState()" callback just for demonstration purposes, but you can pass the value to other components by props or wherever method you prefer. Also, when the checkbox is checked the value will return "true"